# Getting a clear image for a paper with 7.62 mm hole located 50 m away

Tags: image-quality

I have zero experience in photography, but I was trying to know is it possible to get a clear image for a paper with 7.62 millimeter holes located 50 meters away. This is for a project for shooting training in the army.
If yes what kind of lens and camera do I need?

Comment: 7mm or 50mm? Headline and body of question differ

Comment: sorry 7mm I edited the question.

Comment: Clear image?  Do you want to count the holes and know their approximate position?  Or, do you want the hole to fill the camera frame?

Comment: What kind of project? Are you looking to record the shots for later analysis? Are you trying to blow up the target holes in order to display on a screen to display in real-time? Or is this more to be a picture-taking spotting scope?

Comment: @Mattman944 I want to count the holes only and know their approximate position and sorry for late replies.

Comment: @scottbb I want to get the score of the shooter automatically without having someone forced to go and check the wholes in the paper and saved into the system. What my boss have in mind is that we will have a camera, take an image for the target after the shooter finishes, this image will be sent to a computer and after image processing phase the score will be calculated and saved into the db of the system.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am going to assume that you only want to count the holes on a paper target and know their approximate position.

7 mm at 50 meters is 0.008 degrees.

Next we need to make some assumptions on the camera. I will use my equipment, a Canon 7D, APS-C (1.6 crop sensor), about 5000 pixels on the long side.

I would want the holes to be about 10 pixels wide, this is a guess as to how significant you need the holes to be in the camera frame.

10 pixels / 5000 pixels = 1/500 of the frame

0.008 degrees * 500 = 4 degrees field of view

You can achieve this with a 400mm lens, these are fairly common and a decent one is $1000 to $2000. See this [calculator](https://www.pointsinfocus.com/tools/depth-of-field-and-equivalent-lens-calculator/#%7B%22c%22:[%7B%22f%22:9,%22av%22:%228%22,%22fl%22:400,%22d%22:50000,%22cm%22:%220%22%7D],%22m%22:1%7D).

Note that your field of view will be 2.8 x 1.8 meters. This is probably bigger than your target. If you want the target to fill the camera frame, the calculation will be different.

Edit: Test image. 3.5 mm hole at 25 meters. I can't easily do 50 meters.

Canon 7D, 100-400 f5.6 M1 zoom @400 mm, f8, remote flash.

[image]

Zoomed to show actual pixels:

[image]

Comment: This is true if you want to count the holes. Not to take photo of them. Also the hole is "circle" and you should count the short side of sensor!

Comment: IF it is about counting holes, any old $250 worth of 400mm lens will get you 10x10 pixel objects clearly - probably a used $50 70-210 with a $20 Kenko MC7 will. If you want a clearer picture of the holes, a decent 400mm prime also with an x2 converter or two would help...

Comment: So that means it's extremely very hard to achieve this on 50 meters.
@rackandboneman this is assuming the paper is 25 meters far?

Comment: 7 mm at 50 meters will have similar results to 3.5 mm at 25 meters. Was dark and raining outside when I shot these. I have a clear shot across 5 rooms in my house so I can do 25 meters in my house.

Comment: If you are on a budget, rackandboneman's ideas are good. For most of the budget options you will lose autofocus, but that is probably OK for what you are doing. A really cheap option would be a used Canon T4i and this lens https://www.amazon.com/Opteka-650-1300mm-1300-2600mm-Telephoto-Digital/dp/B001VDLZIG/ It won't be as crisp as my lens, but the higher magnification will make up for it. In any case you will need a really solid tripod.

Comment: can nikon p900 do it ?

Comment: @DavidIbrahim - The Nikon P900 looks promising, but I can't tell for sure. Also note that if you want the files to automatically be transferred to a computer, this will take more research.

Answer (score 4):

I think that this sounds more like a case for a remote-triggered camera in short distance before the target under a bullet-proof hood (also consider ricocheting bullets) mounted fixed to the ground or ceiling.  There are cameras without their own controls like the Sony DSC-QX10 that are served from a smartphone, so you can even use it from the stand (assuming that the bullet-proof hood is not Wifi proof).  You'll get better image quality (even with some geometric distortion) at a quite lower price.

A common wisdom for birders "no lens is as good as getting closer" and for a fixed unscarable target this would seem to hold doubly.

Comment: yes, I thought about this but they didn't allow it as they don't want any hardware between the target and the shooter.

Comment: @DavidIbrahim What about placing the camera *behind* the target?

Comment: @PeterM Have you thought that through? if you can see the holes on the back side of the target then ????  Sorry but i have to say it, Maybe you could stand behind the target and hold the camera ? *The comments of Alaska  man are strictly for entertainment purposes. ( mostly Alaska mans entertainment )*

Comment: @AlaskaMan Yes I have thought it through.  Just because the camera is behind the target doesn't mean that it is in line with the target.  Place it at an angle and below the target, and then apply perspective correction to the image.  Being much closer to the target you have pixels to burn with such image manipulations.

Answer (score 1):

Any spotting scope attached with a cheap webcam (HD) should do the trick. Of course my spotting scope is an old Cat (mirror, 500mm), so take that as you will.